# MTOM issue with CXF Client & Metro Webservice

Tags: mtom

I am facing a problem making MTOM work with CXF Client & JAX-WS Webservice.

I am getting the below error when invoking a webservice which is enabled  with MTom

```
Exception Caught: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException (The currentElement is not MtomEnabled [testData: null])
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.testMethod(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The currentElement is not MtomEnabled [testData: null]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:672)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2254)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2134)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1988)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:639)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:484)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
```

The same webservice perfectly works fine with CXF Webservice.
I have also added the annotation `@MTOM(enabled=true)` for webservice
end point.